# Lapply does not work as expected

Tags: data-transformation, function

I want to use map or lapply to iterate over a list of dimension variables (*dim_list* below) using my custom function (*transf_fun()*). My overall goal is to generate a set of tables and later to pass them on to another custom function using ggplot and generate a bunch of graphs.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(surveydata)
library(purrr)

dataframe <- surveydata::membersurvey

# my funciton
transf_fun <- function(dim=Q30){
  dim <- enquo(dim)
  dataframe <- dataframe %>% select(!!dim, Q20_1, Q20_2, Q20_3, Q20_4, Q20_5, 
                                  Q20_6, Q20_7, Q20_8, Q20_9, Q20_10) %>%
  pivot_longer(., cols = c(Q20_1, Q20_2, Q20_3, Q20_4, Q20_5, 
                           Q20_6, Q20_7, Q20_8, Q20_9, Q20_10), names_to = "question_20", 
               values_to = "Val_Q20") %>%
  count(question_20, !!dim, Val_Q20) %>% mutate(countT = sum(n))

df_group <- summarize(group_by(dataframe, question_20, !!dim, Val_Q20), countIN = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(q20n = sum(countIN)) %>%
  mutate(propT = countIN / q20n * 100)

return(df_group)
}
```

The problem arises when I try to generate the tables. When I use my custom function on each dimension variable separately, I get a correct table. However, when I pass a list of dimension variables to *lapply()* or *map()*, all the dimension column values change to the value of the column name.

```
(tab1 <- transf_fun(dim=Q30))
```

Correct table (example #1 - see column *Q30*):

```
> (tab1 <- transf_fun(dim=Q30))
# A tibble: 66 x 6
# Groups:   question_20, Q30 [40]
   question_20 Q30           Val_Q20 countIN  q20n propT
   <chr>       <fct>         <fct>     <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Q20_1       Consultancy   Yes          13   181  7.18
 2 Q20_1       Consultancy   No          168   181 92.8 
 3 Q20_1       Fieldwork     Yes           1    15  6.67
 4 Q20_1       Fieldwork     No           14    15 93.3 
 5 Q20_1       Data analysis Yes           2    12 16.7 
 6 Q20_1       Data analysis No           10    12 83.3 
 7 Q20_1       NA            Yes           1     7 14.3 
 8 Q20_1       NA            No            6     7 85.7 
 9 Q20_10      Consultancy   Yes           7   181  3.87
10 Q20_10      Consultancy   No          174   181 96.1 
# ... with 56 more rows
Warning messages:
1: Factor `Q30` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
2: Factor `Q30` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
3: Factor `Q30` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
4: Factor `Q30` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
5: Factor `Q30` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`
```

```
tab2 <- transf_fun(Q26_1)
```

Correct table (example #2 - see column *Q26_1*):

```
> (tab2 <- transf_fun(Q26_1))
# A tibble: 97 x 6
# Groups:   question_20, Q26_1 [60]
   question_20 Q26_1      Val_Q20 countIN  q20n  propT
   <chr>       <ord>      <fct>     <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 Q20_1       1-5        Yes           3    74   4.05
 2 Q20_1       1-5        No           71    74  95.9 
 3 Q20_1       6-10       Yes           8    79  10.1 
 4 Q20_1       6-10       No           71    79  89.9 
 5 Q20_1       11-20      Yes           3    44   6.82
 6 Q20_1       11-20      No           41    44  93.2 
 7 Q20_1       21-49      Yes           2     8  25   
 8 Q20_1       21-49      No            6     8  75   
 9 Q20_1       50 or more No            4     4 100   
10 Q20_1       NA         Yes           1     6  16.7 
# ... with 87 more rows
Warning messages:
1: Factor `Q26_1` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
2: Factor `Q26_1` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
3: Factor `Q26_1` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
4: Factor `Q26_1` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
5: Factor `Q26_1` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`
```

And so on...

```
tab3 <- transf_fun(Q2)
tab4 <- transf_fun(Q35)
tab5 <- transf_fun(Q33)
tab6 <- transf_fun(Q32)
tab7 <- transf_fun(Q31)
tab8 <- transf_fun(Q27_2)
```

However, when I try using *lapply()* or *map()*, I get incorrect output.

```
dim_list <- list("Q2","Q26_1","Q27_2","Q30","Q31","Q32","Q33","Q35") # don't mind the order, it shouldn't matter, imho

(tab_list <- lapply(dim_list, transf_fun))
```

List of incorrect tables (see columns *Q26_1* and *Q30* - instead of **"1-5"**, **"6-10"**, etc. in *Q26_1* and **"Consultancy"**, **"Fieldwork"**, **"Data Analysis"**, etc in *Q30,* we get values identical to the respective column names; also, the values in column *question_20* change in an unexpected way.):

```
> (tab_list <- lapply(dim_list, transf_fun))
...
...
...
[[2]]
# A tibble: 20 x 6
# Groups:   question_20, "Q26_1" [10]
   question_20 `"Q26_1"` Val_Q20 countIN  q20n  propT
   <chr>       <chr>     <fct>     <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 Q20_1       Q26_1     Yes          17   215  7.91 
 2 Q20_1       Q26_1     No          198   215 92.1  
 3 Q20_10      Q26_1     Yes           9   215  4.19 
 4 Q20_10      Q26_1     No          206   215 95.8  
 5 Q20_2       Q26_1     Yes          15   215  6.98 
 6 Q20_2       Q26_1     No          200   215 93.0  
 7 Q20_3       Q26_1     Yes           3   215  1.40 
 8 Q20_3       Q26_1     No          212   215 98.6  
 9 Q20_4       Q26_1     Yes          34   215 15.8  
10 Q20_4       Q26_1     No          181   215 84.2  
11 Q20_5       Q26_1     Yes           5   215  2.33 
12 Q20_5       Q26_1     No          210   215 97.7  
13 Q20_6       Q26_1     Yes          20   215  9.30 
14 Q20_6       Q26_1     No          195   215 90.7  
15 Q20_7       Q26_1     Yes           1   215  0.465
16 Q20_7       Q26_1     No          214   215 99.5  
17 Q20_8       Q26_1     Yes          37   215 17.2  
18 Q20_8       Q26_1     No          178   215 82.8  
19 Q20_9       Q26_1     Yes           8   215  3.72 
20 Q20_9       Q26_1     No          207   215 96.3 
...
...
...
[[4]]
# A tibble: 20 x 6
# Groups:   question_20, "Q30" [10]
   question_20 `"Q30"` Val_Q20 countIN  q20n  propT
   <chr>       <chr>   <fct>     <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 Q20_1       Q30     Yes          17   215  7.91 
 2 Q20_1       Q30     No          198   215 92.1  
 3 Q20_10      Q30     Yes           9   215  4.19 
 4 Q20_10      Q30     No          206   215 95.8  
 5 Q20_2       Q30     Yes          15   215  6.98 
 6 Q20_2       Q30     No          200   215 93.0  
 7 Q20_3       Q30     Yes           3   215  1.40 
 8 Q20_3       Q30     No          212   215 98.6  
 9 Q20_4       Q30     Yes          34   215 15.8  
10 Q20_4       Q30     No          181   215 84.2  
11 Q20_5       Q30     Yes           5   215  2.33 
12 Q20_5       Q30     No          210   215 97.7  
13 Q20_6       Q30     Yes          20   215  9.30 
14 Q20_6       Q30     No          195   215 90.7  
15 Q20_7       Q30     Yes           1   215  0.465
16 Q20_7       Q30     No          214   215 99.5  
17 Q20_8       Q30     Yes          37   215 17.2  
18 Q20_8       Q30     No          178   215 82.8  
19 Q20_9       Q30     Yes           8   215  3.72 
20 Q20_9       Q30     No          207   215 96.3  
...
...
...
```

The dimensions of the two example tables should be 66×6 and 97×6 respectively, instead of 20×6 each, as it is the case in the output of lapply.

purrr::map() seems to return an identically flawed list of tables:

```
tab_list2 <- map(dim_list, transf_fun) # identical list to the one generated by lapply
```

I don't seem to understand why would a function that works well on it's own, give this unexpected result when used with a list of arguments within lapply() or map().
###########################################################################

### Update:

I have been able to solve this issue. The problem with calling lapply() or map() on my custom function, was that I was giving them a list of strings, while I should have been giving them a list of expressions or a list of names.
i.e., This would work:

```
# list of strings. Incorrect
dim_list <- list("Q2","Q26_1","Q27_2","Q30","Q31","Q32","Q33","Q35")

# let's correct the list by converting strings to names
dim_list <- lapply(dim_list, as.name) # convert the list items to "names"
```

The proper list of arguments looks like this:

```
> lapply(dim_list, as.name)
[[1]]
Q2

[[2]]
Q26_1

[[3]]
Q27_2

[[4]]
Q30

[[5]]
Q31

[[6]]
Q32

[[7]]
Q33

[[8]]
Q35
```

Now the map function call will work properly

```
tab_list3 <- lapply(dim_list, transf_fun) # the correct output of tables
```

Comment: lapply doesn't work with magrittr, basically the thing you need to push the tidyverse syntax  https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/articles/magrittr.html...

Comment: most likely this is more suitable for SO, but I would suggest trimming down your question to the relevant parts...

Comment: So, basically, if I rewrite the transf_fun() without the pipe operators %>%, it should work as expected?